# AngularJs - Adding Custom class on UI-Bootstrap's Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

How can I replace or add a new class on UI-Bootsrap's Tab Nav. I'm expecting something like,

```
<ul class="MY-CUSTOM-CLASS" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="">
       <li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" heading="Justified" class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <a href="" ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Justified</a>
       </li>

       .....          
</ul>
```

I've tried the following but, it's adding the class to the parent,

```
<tabset justified="true" class="tab-nav">
       <tab heading="Justified">Justified content</tab>
       <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
       <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: You want to add a custom class to the `<ul>` instead of the surrounding `<div>`? Do you need this only for one tabset or for all the same and does the value need to be dynamic or static?

Comment: @Numyx Yes, I need the custom class for <ul> tag. I have different classes for different tabsets. Values are static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, what you wan't to do is not supported by the ui bootstrap module, so we need to extend the module to get the requested behavior. To do that we will use decorators:

```
.config(function($provide) {

  // This adds the decorator to the tabset directive 
  // @see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L88 
  $provide.decorator('tabsetDirective', function($delegate) {

    // The `$delegate` contains the configuration of the tabset directive as 
    // it is defined in the ui bootstrap module.
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    // This is the original link method from the directive definition
    var link = directive.link;

    // This sets a compile method to the directive configuration which will provide
    // the modified/extended link method
    directive.compile = function() {

      // Modified link method
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // Call the original `link` method
        link(scope, element, attrs);

        // Get the value for the `custom-class` attribute and assign it to the scope.
        // This is the same the original link method does for the `vertical` and ``justified` attributes
        scope.customClass = attrs.customClass;
      }
    }

    // Return the modified directive
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

This takes the old `link` method of the tabset directive and wraps it with an custom method that in addition to the old method also binds the value of the `custom-class` attribute to the scope. Second thing we need to do is overriding the template to actually use the `scope.customClass` parameter:

There are multiple ways to this either use the `$templateProvider` or maybe simpler way use a `<scrip type="text/ng-template">`:

```
  <script id="template/tabs/tabset.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div>
      <ul class="{{customClass}} nav nav-{{type || 'tabs'}}" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude></ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" tab-content-transclude="tab">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/M3MgEPY6rfGuUda2a2N7?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I would really appreciate if you could explain me above config codes by simple comment on each line.

Comment: @Body Added some comments to the code, hoping it will help you to understand. Unfortunately there is (afaik) no official documentation of how to use decorators, i learned it from this article: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/ .